# Parsing json to list of objects and displaying data in console

Tags: c#, json, webclient

Im trying to access properties of a list of objects that i got from parsing json, but i'm not even sure did it parse correctly.
This is my code:

```
public class Currency
{

    public int Broj_tecajnice { get; set; }
    public string Drzava { get; set; }
    public string Drzava_iso { get; set; }
    public string Sifra_valute { get; set; }
    public string Valuta { get; set; }
    public int Jedinica { get; set; }
    public float Kupovni_tecaj { get; set; }
    public float Srednji_tecaj { get; set; }
    public float Prodajni_tecaj { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient())
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var json = 
client.DownloadString("http://api.hnb.hr/tecajn/v2");
            List<Currency> currencies = 
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Currency>>(json);
            currencies.ForEach(c => 
Console.WriteLine(currencies.ToString()));

        }
    }
}
```

And in short, api looks like this:

```
[{"broj_tecajnice":"85","datum_primjene":"2019-05-01","drzava":"EMU","drzava_iso":"EMU","sifra_valute":"978","valuta":"EUR","jedinica":1,"kupovni_tecaj":"7,388924","srednji_tecaj":"7,411157","prodajni_tecaj":"7,433390"}, {"broj_tecajnice":"85","datum_primjene":"2019-05-01","drzava":"EMU","drzava_iso":"EMU","sifra_valute":"978","valuta":"EUR","jedinica":1,"kupovni_tecaj":"7,388924","srednji_tecaj":"7,411157","prodajni_tecaj":"7,433390"}]
```

and so on, it has 14 objects and i manage to get all 14 objects in a list but i cannot access objects properties

Comment: That to string call looks incorrect. You need to construct a string using the properties of the object. Everything else looks as it should.

Comment: can you show with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That to string call looks incorrect. You need to construct a string using the properties of the object in the collection.

For example

```
currencies.ForEach(c => 
    Console.WriteLine($"drzava_iso: {c.Drzava_iso}, Sifra_valute: {c.Sifra_valute}, ...")
);
```

Everything else looks as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `c` parameter in the `Action` of the `ForEach` function :

In case you have overriden `ToString` in your `Currency` class :

```cs
currencies.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine(c.ToString()));
```

Else, you can call a delegate :

```cs
currencies.ForEach(delegate(Currency c)
{
    // make your ToString() function here or any other code
    Console.WriteLine(c.Broj_tecajnice);
});
```

Read more abour `ForEach` : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netframework-4.7